# iOS deployment fails with error "Selected device is not a physical device. Please select a valid device before deploying the application."

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using VS-2017 on a Windows PC. I can test and run the iOS application using simulators.

1. Now I started to build the App for the AppStore.
2. Building succeeds.
3. Now I select "Deploy..." in the project solution menu.
4. Nothing happens.

The Xamarin Log just shows one new line:
"Selected device is not a physical device. Please select a valid device before deploying the application."

The App was build and signed.

How can I upload my App to the store?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308357/generating-the-ipa-file-of-my-xamarin-app-without-an-ios-device?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to connect with a Mac:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/index

Alternatively archive your app into a .ipa and use a Mac and Application Loader.app:
https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdS673accdb

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things,

First is to deploy. It means you are installing the application to your iPhone.

Second thing is to publish: For that you will need a developer account you will have to setup the application and then you can publish it for the other user's to install.

Now, if you wants to test it on your device, attach the physical iPhone and select it while deploy to see app running on it.

Hope it clears.